# Generate network traffic on a wireless Windows device

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, traffic, generator

I need to generate as much network traffic as possible from a laptop running windows (connected to the internet via Wifi). The kind of traffic itself is not important.

How may I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to generate as much Internet traffic as possible or as much WiFi traffic as possible?

Comment: As much Wifi as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of freeware traffic generators available. If you want to do it for free, place a very large file on a server and download it 5 or 6 times simultaneously from the same PC or laptop.

Prior to doing this, open 12 command prompts, size and arrange them all and copy and paste the command `ping (local server IP) -t` into each. Once the download starts hit enter on each prompt one at a time.

That should give the network something to think about. Watch a video on BBC iPlayer, YouTube, or Netflix over the wireless at the same time just to really kill it.